# Save passwords in Chrome on broken SSL sites

Tags: google-chrome, credential-manager

When a website does not have a valid SSL certificate **Chrome** does not allow saving passwords.

Is there a workaround or a flag to enable this?

Comment: I would be wonderful if someone finds a solution for this!